# Copy text to first empty cell

Tags: javascript, if-statement, cell

I have a script that does the following. When I put a note for "Person1" in F5 (Columns C,D, and E have other data) that note populates in B38 because A38 is "Person1" and  the next time that I set a note for "Person1" in maybe  F20 (From B5:B36 there is a drop down list that can choose any person that is in A38:A100 that's why the note for "Person1" can be in F5:F36) and run the script it populates into C38. However, my issue is that if the first time that I run the script  "Person1" does not have a note it leaves B38 blank and lets say I go in tomorrow and  "Person1" does have a note then it adds the note in C38 not B38 even though B38 is blank.

here is an example image
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EjGhcvXJOklP4qOH9XNAwFiO2OwwTWELEgZcJDvTbU4/edit?usp=sharing

```
function autoload(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var meeting = ss.getRange("B5:R36").getValues(); 
  var targetNames = ss.getRange("A38:A100").getValues();
  var writtingRange = ss.getRange("B38:R100").getValues();
  var updatedUser = targetNames;
  var writtingColumn = -1;
  var coolMatrix;

  for(var i = 0; i < meeting.length; i++){ 
    var name = meeting[i][0] 
    for (var j = 0; j < targetNames.length; j++) { 
      if (targetNames[j][0] == name){
        for (var z = 0; z < writtingRange[0].length; z++) { 
          if (writtingRange[j][z] == '' && writtingColumn < 0) { 
            writtingColumn = z; 
            break; 
          }
        }
        writtingRange[j][writtingColumn] = meeting[i][4];
        updatedUser[j] = true; 
      }
    }
  }
  for (var w = 0; w < writtingRange.length; w++){
    if (writtingRange[w][writtingColumn] == ''){
      writtingRange[w][writtingColumn] = ' ';
    }
  }
  ss.getRange("B38:R100").setValues(writtingRange);
}
```

I believe it is missing maybe a If statement? I am pretty new to scripting and not sure what to do.
Any help would be appreciated :) Thank you

Comment: `"However, my issue is..."`. Is that an issue or is there an issue with your code, that you don't know? Did you run your code and encounter any issues?

Comment: @Udo E.  I did run the code and it works there are no issues. I just want to add maybe an **IF** statement that says if the cell before is empty (in range B38:R100) then add the note to that empty cell like I showed in the image link I added.

Comment: You can edit your question to capture your exact requirements. As-is, It is very unclear.

Comment: I just edited I hope it is clearer. Thank you. I can also link the spreadsheet if that makes it easier

Comment: The image link isn't legible at all.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OcXCbahsmGxEFZiRM2EZOggVvgMdEOWlAgeX1vLD4BE/edit?usp=sharing.  Oh weird I am able to see it just fine but Here is the link the the sheet maybe that's better you can reference Tab AV Rotation